# How to use Backdrop shadow with Popper?

Tags: material-ui

Similar to how the Drawer/Dialog drop the backdrop shadow, how can I do the same with Popper component?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the [Backdrop](https://material-ui.com/api/backdrop/) component.  Here is an example, using the [Simple Popper demo code](https://material-ui.com/utils/popper/#simple-popper) as a starting point:

```
class SimplePopper extends React.Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null,
    open: false
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    const { currentTarget } = event;
    this.setState(state => ({
      anchorEl: currentTarget,
      open: !state.open
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { anchorEl, open } = this.state;
    const id = open ? "simple-popper" : null;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Backdrop open={open} onClick={() => this.setState({ open: false })} />
        <div>
          <Button
            aria-describedby={id}
            variant="contained"
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            Toggle Popper
          </Button>
          <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} transition>
            {({ TransitionProps }) => (
              <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
                <Paper>
                  <Typography className={classes.typography}>
                    The content of the Popper.
                  </Typography>
                </Paper>
              </Fade>
            )}
          </Popper>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Note the key addition here of:

```
<Backdrop open={open} onClick={() => this.setState({ open: false })} />
```

Since the `Backdrop` component is using the same `open` state for its `open` prop as the `Popper` component, it will appear whenever the popper is open.

The `onClick` prop allows the user to dismiss the popper and backdrop by clicking anywhere on the backdrop. If you don't want this functionality, then you can exclude the prop:

```
<Backdrop open={open} />
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/q76pn8pk9?fontsize=14